# BlackBerry not communicating with new Exchange

Tags: exchange-2010, bes

I have just migrated mailboxes to a new Exchange 2010 server.

BlackBerry Enterprise Server is not communicating with the new Exchange. I was prompted to enter the usernames & Exchange server name, but BlackBerry is still not communicating with it.

Can someone please assist me on how to troubleshoot this system?

[image: BlackBerry Manager]

Comment: What Exchange server name did you enter?

Comment: servername.domain.local

Comment: But which server is that?  It'll need to be the CAS server.  Also, are you running up-to-date BES and the MAPI CDO?

Comment: That is the Exchange 2010 server. BES was connecting fine with an Exchange 2007 server. Surely there's a quick settings change within BES to connect it to the Exchange 2010 server?

Comment: There are a lot of things that can break a BES connection to the Exchange server when you change Exchange versions.  Again, check the BES and MAPI CDO versions.  And check whether the BES account has the correct permissions for it to function against the 2010 server.  And have you moved the BES service account's mailbox to the 2010 server and updated the MAPI settings when that occurred?

Comment: BES version is 4.1.5. I installed "Microsoft Messaging API and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1" on the BlackBerry server. The BESAdmin mailbox is under Exchange 2010 with the required permissions. When you say MAPI settings, are you referring to the "Edit MAPI Profile" on the BlackBerry server? If so, yes this authenticates using the BESAdmin login against the Exchange server name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade the BES software.  4.1 doesn't work with Exchange 2010; you'll need 5.0.

See the [compatibility document](http://us.blackberry.com/support/software/server_exchange_ver_jan_6_12.pdf) for more detail.